# Multiple services dependencies state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, flux

So the problem I'm facing is a non normalized state on my event-driven app: After an action or event is dispatched, several subscribers will execute in order. But after the first subscriber is executed, it triggers a new action which also has several subscribers, and so on. At some point, some subscriber is going to require data from other models that depend on the first action, but haven't been updated yet. See the diagram: 
[image]

So what is the better way to accomplish this with redux and its normalized state? And what is the formal name for this problem?

Comment: You can write the reducer so that every part of the state is updated given the right action is dispatched. However since you're dealing with a lot of side effects you can tackle this problem with the combination of redux with [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga). It enables you to write more complex scenario's in a clear and mantainable way.

Comment: The formal name for this problem is called **[Redux Side Effects](https://medium.com/javascript-and-opinions/redux-side-effects-and-you-66f2e0842fc3#.fsa9cdusw)**